# Unity 5.4 find the length of the object

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

hi every one i am using Unity 5.4.1f1 to create a simple game , i want my code to add platforms which is a piece  of the street at the end of the first platform , with out hard coding the street length which is 14 m

so i tried this code : 
i added in start :

```
lastPos = platForm.transform.position;
size = platForm.transform.localScale.z;
```

and added called this code in update :

```
Vector3 currentPos = lastPos;
```

currentPos.z +=size; 
    lastPos =currentPos; 
    Instantiate(platForm,lastPos,Quaternion.identity);

but it did't work it always get the size 1 even if it is 14 
so is that doable in unity or i should do it hard coded ?

[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting the `size` to change if you never modify the scale value?

Comment: @UnholySheep this just the template i want to use the code for another kinds of platforms with different sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use renderer.bounds

For example

```
var size  = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
```

Answer (score 2):

The scale represent a multiplier to the size of the object. 
So a object with 10m but with no scale will return the factor 1, if you duplicate the size of that model (20 m) the scale will be 2.

You can get the length of a mesh though its bounds

mesh.bounds.size, this vector3 will have a lengths for each axis.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html

Comment: I didn't saw that your object was without a collider, you can use the mesh with the same idea, I edit my first post.